# sending data from device to remote server

Tags: java, android

My application is passing two value from device to remote server but it work in when i tested in bluestack when I install in real device it show a message like "Unfortunately app has been stooped" so I can't under stand where is problem i delete and clean device temporary and cache memory of device still not getting output.

following is my source code

```
package com.androidexample.httpgetexample;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpGetAndroidExample extends Activity {

    TextView content;
    EditText fname,email,login,pass;
    Spinner sp;
    Button b1;
    String s[] = { "Courtage Problem", "Cartage Refil", "Printer Problem",
    "Printer Drivers" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_http_get_android_example);

        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);
        fname   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        sp  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s);
        sp.setAdapter(ad);
        ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);


        saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   
                //ALERT MESSAGE
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please wait, connecting to server.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try{    

                String n = URLEncoder.encode(fname.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                String d = URLEncoder.encode(sp.getSelectedItem().toString(), "UTF-8");

                    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String URL = "http://shreebijapur.in/Customerquery.aspx?n="+n+"&d="+d;

                    //Log.i("httpget", URL);
                    try
                    {
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                        String SetServerString = "";
                        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                        content.setText(SetServerString);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        content.setText("Fail!");
                    }
                }
                catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
                {
                    content.setText("Fail111");
                }       
            }
        });  
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the crash

Comment: post your logcat messages..

Comment: Use Volley to POST data from device to server.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably crashing due to the networkOnMainThreadException. I'm trying to executr an http request in an inner class that `extends` class `AsyncTask`.

I put all network related stuff in the `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

**If Error: networkOnMainThreadException**

Perform http request execution in an inner class that `extends` the class `AsyncTask`.

or

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
               // HERE_YOUR_HTTP_REQUEST CODE
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            }
        }.execute();
```

Try this 
Or 
You can use volley, retrofit or other networking library's for API call.